# How to make a whole docker container volatile?

Tags: linux, performance, docker, docker-compose, ramdisk

I need to use a (bad) image with a lot of I/O inside its container. So I have a lot of I/O on my disk.
I would like the whole container not to write to the disk but only to memory (tmpfs). I don't care if this data is lost because I made volumes for the data that needs to be persistent.

The most important I/O (pidstat) is done for example with the file `/usr/lib/unifi/lib/ace.jar`. I can't mount `/usr/lib/unifi/lib/` in tmpfs because I will get the error "Error: Unable to access jarfile".

How to make a whole docker container volatile?

Comment: Releated/possible dulicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39193419/docker-in-memory-file-system

Comment: I agree that https://stackoverflow.com/a/39312620/421195 is probably a good solution.  But I'm curious why mounting /usr/lib/unifi/xxx on tmpfs would cause ""Error: Unable to access jarfile".  I'm also curious where "ace.jar" is doing all of its I/O?  Directly in /sr/lib/unifi/lib (or directly with the .jar file itself)?

Comment: @paulsm4 The command in this case that constantly writes is `java -Xmx1024M -jar /usr/lib/unifi/lib/ace.jar start`. 
I don't want to worry about the content of this image, I'd just like to put it in RAM so it doesn't wear out my precious disk.

I think the `Error: Unable to access jarfile` is because my try `tmpfs: /usr/lib/unifi/lib` starts an empty directory (this is not anticipated by the image).